# how can i compare DTO classes with JsonResponse and check if any Node which is present in DTO is missing in Response class?

Tags: java, json, rest-assured-jsonpath

I had a Complex Pojo class in Java which contains multiple classes as attributes. Let's call it my DTO. Now I am using an Object Mapper which Maps a JSON mapper to that class.

Now my problem is that I need a method to check if My Response contains all field present in DTO class. If that is NUll or if the node is missing it should return me the difference that it is null. I tried the below code, but that is checking at **first level only**. Suppose my DTO class name is  Sample

I am initializing Sample s = new Sample(); # this is not initializing the classes which are present as attributes inside. thus "differences" showing that all nodes are NULL when the comparison is done and mapping Sample using Objectmapper as :

Sample s  = objectMapper.readValue(response, Sample.class);

```
public static List<String> compareObjects(Object obj1, Object obj2) throws IllegalAccessException {
    List<String> differences = new ArrayList<>();

    if (obj1 == null || obj2 == null) {
        differences.add("One or both objects are null");
        return differences;
    }

    Class<?> obj1Class = obj1.getClass();

    for (Field field : obj1Class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);

        Object obj1Value = field.get(obj1);
        Object obj2Value = field.get(obj2);

        if (obj1Value == null && obj2Value == null) {
            continue;
        }

        if (obj1Value == null || obj2Value == null) {
            if (isDTO(field.getType())) {
                differences.add(String.format("%s is null in %s", field.getName(), obj1Value == null ? "obj1" : "obj2"));
            }
        } else if (isDTO(obj1Value.getClass())) {
            differences.addAll(compareObjects(obj1Value, obj2Value));
        } else if (!obj1Value.equals(obj2Value)) {
            differences.add(String.format("%s is different: %s (obj1) vs %s (obj2)", field.getName(), obj1Value, obj2Value));
        }
    }

    return differences;
}

private static boolean isDTO(Class<?> clazz) {
    // Replace with the fully qualified name of your DTO class
    return clazz.getCanonicalName().startsWith("com.example.dto");
}
```